# Combinar múltiplas Expressões Regulares em uma só

Tags: python, regex

Existe alguma forma de se combinar múltiplos padrões de regex em uma única expressão, para ser usado no `re.match()` ou `re.search()`, por exemplo?

```
starts_with_Y = '([Y][A-Za-z0-9]{6}([-][A-Za-z0-9]{1})?\s)'
starts_with_t = '([t][a-zA-Z][][A-Za-z0-9]{3}[][A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9])?\s)'
starts_with_Q = '([Q]\d{4}\s)'
starts_with_RDN = '(\b(\w*RDN\d{1,2}[-]\d\w*)\b)'
starts_with_snR = '(\b(\w*snR\d{1,3}([-][A-Za-z0-9])?\w*)\b[ ])'
starts_with_NME = '(NME\d{1}[ ])'
starts_with_ICR = '(ICR\d{1}[ ])'
starts_with_LSR = '(LSR\d{1}[ ])'
```

Necessito de um único regex, pois a aplicação faz a leitura de um arquivo de texto linha por linha, e em cada linha aparece apenas um de cada. Exemplo:

```
D      YHR077C NMD2; Nmd2p  K14327 UPF2; regulator of nonsense transcripts 2
D      YGR072W UPF3; Upf3p  K14328 UPF3; regulator of nonsense transcripts 3
D      snR19 SNR19  K14276 U1snRNA; U1 spliceosomal RNA
D      LSR1 LSR1    K14277 U2snRNA; U2 spliceosomal RNA
D      snR14 SNR14  K14278 U4snRNA; U4 spliceosomal RNA
D      snR7-S SNR7-S    K14279 U5snRNA; U5 spliceosomal RNA
D      snR7-L SNR7-L    K14279 U5snRNA; U5 spliceosomal RNA
D      snR6 SNR6    K14280 U6snRNA; U6 spliceosomal RNA
D      snR17a SNR17A    K14483 U3snoRNA; U3 small nucleolar RNA
D      snR17b SNR17B    K14483 U3snoRNA; U3 small nucleolar RNA
```

E é possível usar o `re.compile()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se cada linha só pode dar *match* em uma das expressões, uma opção é usar [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), através do caractere `|`.

Basicamente, basta fazer `expressao1|expressao2|expressao3...`. Assim, a regex vai testando cada uma das alternativas, até que algum *match* seja encontrado. No caso, para montar esta regex, vou usar [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) para unir todas as expressões de uma vez.

Outro detalhe é que o `\` deve ser escapado (escrito como `\\`, por estar dentro de strings). Do jeito que está, o `\b` é interpretado como o [caractere BACKSPACE](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#index-22). Para que ele seja interpretado como o [*word boundary*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) de regex (que acredito ser a intenção), a `\` precisaria ser escapada.
Mas geralmente, em Python, é melhor usar [*raw string literals*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2081708) para regex, colocando um `r` na frente das aspas de abertura, assim a `\` não precisa de escape:

```
import re

starts_with_Y = r'([Y][A-Za-z0-9]{6}([-][A-Za-z0-9]{1})?\s)'
starts_with_t = r'([t][a-zA-Z][][A-Za-z0-9]{3}[][A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9])?\s)'
starts_with_Q = r'([Q]\d{4}\s)'
starts_with_RDN = r'(\b(\w*RDN\d{1,2}[-]\d\w*)\b)'
starts_with_snR = r'(\b(\w*snR\d{1,3}([-][A-Za-z0-9])?\w*)\b[ ])'
starts_with_NME = r'(NME\d{1}[ ])'
starts_with_ICR = r'(ICR\d{1}[ ])'
starts_with_LSR = r'(LSR\d{1}[ ])'

r = re.compile('|'.join([starts_with_Y, starts_with_t, starts_with_Q, starts_with_RDN, starts_with_snR, starts_with_NME, starts_with_ICR, starts_with_LSR]))
```

Com isso, a regex passa a ser `starts_with_Y`, ou `starts_with_t`, ou `starts_with_Q`, etc. Um possível uso seria:

```
for linha in arquivo:
    m = r.search(linha)
    if m: # foi encontrado um match na linha
        print(m.group()) # obter o trecho encontrado pelo match
```

---

Dá para simplificar as expressões.

Quando você só quer capturar um único caractere, não precisa dos colchetes, então `[Y]` é o mesmo que `Y`. Até mesmo `[ ]` para espaço, pode ser trocado por um espaço mesmo (embora nesse caso específico pode não ficar tão claro que há um espaço). Já `[]` não quer dizer nada e pode ser removido (corresponde a literalmente "nada" - ou, dependendo da linguagem/engine, é considerada uma expressão inválida).

E `{1}` quer dizer "exatamente uma ocorrência", mas por padrão, qualquer coisa colocada em uma regex - sem um [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) - corresponde a uma ocorrência daquela coisa (`x{1}` é o mesmo que `x`), então isso pode ser removido também.

`[A-Za-z0-9]{3}[A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9])?` quer dizer que `[A-Za-z0-9]` ocorre 3 vezes, depois mais uma vez, e [opcionalmente](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) mais uma vez. Ou seja, isso pode ocorrer 4 ou 5 vezes, então bastaria fazer `[A-Za-z0-9]{4,5}` - a sintaxe `{x,y}` quer dizer "no mínimo x vezes, e no máximo y vezes".

Por fim, as 3 últimas expressões são bem parecidas (3 letras específicas seguidas de um número e um espaço), então você poderia juntá-las em `((NME|ICR|LSR)\d )` (começa com "NME" ou "ICR" ou "LSR", seguido de número e espaço).

Resumindo, poderia ficar assim:

```
starts_with_Y = r'(Y[A-Za-z0-9]{6}(-[A-Za-z0-9])?\s)'
starts_with_t = r'(t[a-zA-Z][A-Za-z0-9]{4,5}\s)'
starts_with_Q = r'(Q\d{4}\s)'
starts_with_RDN = r'(\b(\w*RDN\d{1,2}-\d\w*)\b)'
starts_with_snR = r'(\b(\w*snR\d{1,3}(-[A-Za-z0-9])?\w*)\b )'
starts_with_NME_ICR_LSR = r'((NME|ICR|LSR)\d )'

r = re.compile('|'.join([starts_with_Y, starts_with_t, starts_with_Q, starts_with_RDN, starts_with_snR, starts_with_NME_ICR_LSR]))
```

Comment: Perfeito, muito agradecido.